# Fixed background on mobile device

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am having trouble setting the background of this page - http://troov.co/team/ (on a mobile device) so that the background image is fixed, and just the content scrolls down.

At the moment, the background image scrolls down with the content, meaning that there's a lot of white space and so the text underneath the photos is not viewable.

I've tried fixing the width and the height at 100% and putting `background-attachment: fixed;`

Perhaps I'm putting it in the wrong place, but none of these solutions are working. Would really appreciate any help please.

The CSS code is as follows:

```
.container-fluid.team {
  background-image: url(../images/bg_teampage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: please include relevant code in your question in addition to the link

Comment: Will do, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply the fixed background to the `body`:

```
body {
  background-image: url(../images/bg_teampage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below CSS styles:

```
body{
   overflow:hidden;
   }

.container-fluid.team {
background-image: url(../images/bg_teampage.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 163%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While your background is fixed, the div it's applied to is not.   You can set "container-fluid team" to be position absolute and do some z-index stuff,  or you can attach your fixed background image to the body of the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `background-image` inside `.container-fluid` you could add `position:fixed` and `overflow-y: scroll` to `.container-fluid.team` like this:

```
.container-fluid.team {
   background-image: url(../images/bg_teampage.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   position: fixed;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Otherwise I would've moved the background to the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of an old bug from iOS Safari where they didn't support `background-attachment: attached;` but I thought they fixed this bug a year or so ago. Do you mind telling us what device/OS/browser you are testing this on?

I use to attempt to fix this issue by creating a full size div and sending it to the back (negative z-index).

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id='background'></div>
  <!-- Actual Page Content Here -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#background {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.jpg);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -999999999;
}
```

I remember there being a few different plugins/libraries I would use to automate this and give other functionality. But I have not seen this issue in at least a year sense an iOS update.

Check out the jQuery [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) plugin.